# Prove if $A$ is a square matrix there exist non-zero matrix $B$ such as $BA=0$, then $A$ is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove if $A$ is a square matrix there exist non-zero matrix $B$ such as $BA=0$, then $A$ is not invertible.

Does this mean I have to search for a $B$ matrix first?

Then what is my first step to do it?

I also saw similar question but it was $AB=0$, is it any different from my question? I don't really understand either one though.

Comment: Maybe you would find it easier to understand the (equivalent) contrapositive statement: if $A$ is invertible, then $BA = 0$ will only hold if $B$ is the zero-matrix.

Comment: Oh my. Why didn't I think of that sooner. I'm facepalming so hard rn. I was too focused on the matrix I completely forgot the contrapositive statement. I understand it now. Thank you very much!

Comment: If $A$ is invertible then it has full range, so if $BA = 0$ then $By=0$ for all $y$ and hence $B=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ was invertible we could multiply both sides on the right by $A^{-1}$ and get $B=0$.